# Deleting Entities with one-to-many relationships

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle entity deletion for my particular scenario. I have three entities: Item, Purchase, and PurchaseJoin.

Purchase: Has a one-to-many relationship to PurchaseJoin.

Item: Has a one-to-many relationship to PurchaseJoin.

So I will not be deleting any Purchases, their history will always remain. Items will be deleted though. Items have a price and name, which are the attributes I will need to keep a track of if an item is deleted.

What is the best way to delete items, but still keep relevant information about any purchases that Item was a part of?

My thought was to make the PurchaseJoin to Item relationship NULLIFY on delete, but add attributes of Item needed to PurchaseJoin.

Answer (score 1):

Click on relationship attribute and under Inspector section click Data model Inspector-> Delete Rule

Set Delete Rule as No-Action

this may serve your purpose

Comment: When this option is selected, the Item will be deleted, but the relationship will remain intact? Does that mean the relationship will still be able to access attributes of the deleted Item, or are they actually deleted?